# Assigning dynamic key as ID in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know how to assign a dynamic value as the ID while converting the json data fetched from the Firebase Real-Time Database. The code is as below:

```
class Products {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;

  Products({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl
  });

  factory Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Products(
        id: map['id'],        //This is the area of concern
        title: map['title'],
        description: map['description'],
        price: map['price'],
        imageUrl: map['imageUrl']
    );
  }
}
```

This is the class meant for making an API call to fetch the response from the Firebase Realtime Databse.

```
class ProductItems with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, Products> _items = {};

  String? token;

  void update(authToken, items) {
    token = authToken;
    _items = items;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Map<String, Products> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }
Future<Products> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
    final url = Uri.https('form-app-c5343-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com', '/products.json?auth=$token');
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader : 'Basic $token'
    });
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Response : ${json.decode(response.body)}');
      notifyListeners();
      return Products.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }
    else {
      throw Exception("Cannot Authenticate");
    }
  }
```

The Firebase Response :

```
    {
  "products" : {
    "-MfbcM0c0b-dix_KGok1" : {
      "description" : "A red shirt - it is pretty red!",
      "imageUrl" : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg",
      "price" : 29.99,
      "title" : "Red Shirt"
    },
    "-MfbcVOJI_VaOaiJJz_P" : {
      "description" : "A nice pair of trousers.",
      "imageUrl" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg",
      "price" : 59.99,
      "title" : "Trousers"
    },
    "-Mfbiyy3wLiM7gl0bblW" : {
      "description" : "Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.",
      "imageUrl" : "https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg",
      "price" : 19.99,
      "title" : "Yellow Scarf"
    }
  }
}
```

"products" is the key I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your response as in your question in variable `response`, the following will return a list of `Products` with `id` and other values:

```
List<Products> products = response["products"]!.entries //this part is changed
    .map((entry) => Products(
        id: entry.key,
        title: entry.value["title"].toString(),
        description: entry.value["description"].toString(),
        price: double.parse(entry.value["price"].toString()),
        imageUrl: entry.value["imageUrl"].toString()))
    .toList();
```

And if you have one record:

```
static final record = {
  "-MfbcM0c0b-dix_KGok1": {
    "description": "A red shirt - it is pretty red!",
    "imageUrl":
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg",
    "price": 29.99,
    "title": "Red Shirt"
  },
};
```

Your `factory` can be like this:

```
factory Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  return Products(
      id: map.keys.elementAt(0),
      title: map.values.elementAt(0)["title"],
      description: map.values.elementAt(0)["description"],
      price: map.values.elementAt(0)["price"],
      imageUrl: map.values.elementAt(0)["imageUrl"].toString());
}
```

So this will return on `Products` object:

```
Products product = Products.fromJson(record);
```

Comment: I should have put in my entire code while posting the question and I'm totally apologetic for it.  I have edited the question with the entire code. Would it be ok if you can let me know how to implement your solution in that? Thank You In Advance

Comment: What is the desired output from `fetchAndSetProducts()`? A list of `Products` objects from `response.body`, where this body is exactly as in your question?

Comment: I think it is a little confusing to call your class `Products`, it should be rather `Product`. When you receive a set of products from Firebase, you would expect `Products.fromJson` to return a list, but it will only return one product.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I have just edited my Firebase Response. The key is actually supposed to be "products" and not the generic firebase ID's that I wanted to be stored earlier.

Comment: @coolhack7 It means only a small modification, I edited my answer, please check and come back if you have still problems.